Need to share data from Main Activity with Fragments managed by NavController
I have a very simple main activity with some state that I need to share with fragments being managed by a DrawerLayout and NavigationView hosted in the main activity layout
Can someone show a simple example of how to do this?   I've spent quite a bit of time searching and see referrences and examples of using ViewModels (which makes sense) but none of the exmaples seem to align with my stuation.
